# mysql php search engine displaying nothing

Tags: php, mysql

im just playing around when creating a mini search engine, i have results in my sql database, i have added the corrent host user and password with the correct db selected, but when i search something on the site i just get nothing, just a white screen with the search bar at the top. I am not even getting an error saying nothing could be found in the data base?

If i enter the wrong details i get an error, so i know the details are correct.

Any ideas?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Search Engine - Search</title>
<body>

    <h2>Search Engine</h2>
    <form action='./search.php' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='k' size='50' value='<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>' />
        <input type='submit' value='Search'>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <?php
        $k = $_GET['k'];
        $terms = explode(" ", $k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1)
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            else
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }

        //connect
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
        mysql_select_db('search');

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $url = $row['url'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];

                echo "<h1><a href='$url'>$title</a></h1>
                $keywords<br /><br />";
            }
        }

    ?>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: post the contents of `$query`

Comment: PHP initializes variables automatically `$i++` without a properly initialization such as `$i = 0`, it will still making `$i` equal to 1.

Comment: Why are you putting every thing inside `head` ??

Comment: @FuzzyTree what do you mean, what am i supposed to change, i thought i was?

Comment: @LuzanBaral Was just messing around, that wouldn't make a difference to it showing results or not lol.

Comment: It means that since your code is correct, the `consult` might being  returning an empty result. That's why is displaying nothing. Echo your query and use the `phpmyadmin` to see if the query works there.

Comment: @Verhaeren Thanks, i played around and seemed to find the issue. Do you know if its possible in php, for me to be able to enter a keyword and have it query every column rather than just the one?

Comment: I don't get what you're saying. You might ask a new question about that with more information to see what it's about. Happy to help.